# Extracting substring from a filename and saving it to a variable in SSIS

Tags: c#, ssis

I am not able to extract filename and save it to a variable in SSIS. I am trying to save a sub string of a filename if and only if it matches the pattern in regex in VIn.

For example:

EIRSRequest_INC9999999.csv //this should extract INC9999999 and save it to VIn variable

```
public void Main()
{
    String source = @"F:\";
    //String destination = @"F:\";
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"EIRSRequest_(?<val>[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})");
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(source);
    //FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(di.GetFiles);

    foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
    {
        var match = regex.Match(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name));

        if (match.Success)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["val"].Value);

               Dts.Variables["User::vIn"].Value= match.Groups["val"].Value;
            //Console.WriteLine(ticket);

            //File.Move(source + "\\" + fi.Name, destination + "\\" + fi.Name);
            //Console.WriteLine("This is a new line");

            break;
        }
    }

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem you're facing?

Comment: It is not saving the substring of the filename to the variable

Comment: val only has the items in the parenthesis in the regex pattern.  So you will only get the characters after the underscore.

Comment: 1.) What substring? I don't see you're doing a substring anywhere. And 2.) Which variable?

Comment: The script extracts the substring from filename if and only if it matches the specified regex and it is suppose to save the substring to "VIn". The Script compiles fine but it does not save the substring to the VIn variable

Comment: Can you please edit the question to include a valid file name (one that will match the `Regex`)?

Comment: I have edited the post

Comment: OK now I understood the question. Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't know what `Dts` is and how it's initialized.

Answer (score 0):

For an SSIS Script task variable to be updated, the variable should be set up as 'Read/Write' variable.

[image]

Add your variable to ReadWriteVariables and check.

You should be able to see the official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.tasks.scripttask.scripttask.readwritevariables?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sqlserver-2017#Microsoft_SqlServer_Dts_Tasks_ScriptTask_ScriptTask_ReadWriteVariables) as well.

> The comma-delimited list of existing variables made available to the package by the user for read/write access.

Comment: Is it ok if VIn is initially empty?

Comment: I checked the script setting and I have what you mentioned

Comment: Looking more closely, your source and destination path looks to be the same. So, likely `File.Move` is failing,

Comment: I commented that out... trying to see what is wrong