# Passing filename from SSIS script task

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ssis, etl, script-task

I'm attempting to create a SSIS package that loads a flat file into a SQL server table.

I've been able to piece the loading functionality together. I'm currently stuck on passing the filename if it's found from the script task back to a variable where I'd like to use it in the flat file connection string.

```vb
Public Sub Main()
        '
        Dim di As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo("\\winshare\iFile\Cors2\AAA\AAA Employee Incentive Source Data\")

        Dim fi As FileInfo() = di.GetFiles("AAA Full PreReg Report*.csv")

        If fi.Length > 0 Then
            Dts.Variables("User::fileExists").Value = True
            Dts.Variables("User::FileName").Value = fi.name
        Else
            Dts.Variables("User::fileExists").Value = False
        End If

        ' Add your code here
        '
        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
    End Sub
```

I'm seeking help with 
`Dts.Variables("User::FileName").Value = fi.name`

Why won't this work?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use the out of the box feature of `Foreach Enumerator`?

Comment: is it a data type issue as you are not casting? It seems like fi might be an array and not a string

Comment: What does not work ? Are you getting any exceptions ? Have you set your variable as [Read/Write][1] ?


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51598743/extracting-substring-from-a-filename-and-saving-it-to-a-variable-in-ssis/51599285#51599285

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to get the first file in the directory then you can use the following line of code:

```
Dts.Variables("User::FileName").Value = fi(0).name
```

But If you are looking to loop over files then i recommend using the Foreach loop container to loop over files and store each file name within a variable:

- [SSIS - How to loop through files in folder and get path+file names and finally execute stored Procedure with parameter as Path + Filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38151342/ssis-how-to-loop-through-files-in-folder-and-get-pathfile-names-and-finally-e)
- [FAQ - How to loop through files in a specified folder, load one by one and move to archive folder using SSIS](https://help.sentryone.com/dtsxchange/scr/FAQ%20-%20How%20to%20loop%20through%20files%20in%20a%20specified%20folder,%20load%20one%20by%20one%20and%20move%20to%20archive%20folder%20using%20SSIS.htm)